# Django: Show html page and call a view function

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I'm working on a competition project and I have a view function that generates the calendar, but it's function takes a long time and I will like to show an html page with a `<progress>` and call this function.

the views:

```
def createCalendar(request):
  #do something that takes a long time
  return =render_to_response('competition/createdsuccesfull.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def loadingCalendar(request):
    #dosomething        render_to_response('competition/loadingcalendar.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I dont know how to do it, if I can call the view and the html in same line or i have to add a function call in the html or add a css or javascript code.

Thanks,

Comment: You'll need to use AJAX to establish what you want.

Comment: Thanks i have do it with ajax!